# Advice on processing giant text file and processing URL's

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, large-files

I'm currently trying to loop through a text file that is about 1.5gb's in size and then use the URL's that are grabbed from it to pull down the html from the site.

For speed I'm trying to process all the HTTP request on a new thread but since C# is not my strongest language but a requirement for what I'm doing I'm a bit confused on good thread practice.

This is how I'm processing the list

```
private static void Main()
    {
        const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("dump.txt"))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
        {
            String line;
            var progress = 0;

            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var stuff = line.Split('|');
                getHTML(stuff[3]);

                progress += 1;
                Console.WriteLine(progress);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm pulling down the HTML as so

```
 private static void getHTML(String url)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var client = new DecompressGzipResponse();
            var html = client.DownloadString(url);

        }).Start();
    }
```

Though the speeds are fast doing this initially, after about 20 thousand they slow down and eventually after 32 thousand the application will hang and crash. I was under the impression C# threads terminated when the function completed?

Can anyone give any examples/ suggestions on how to do this better?

Comment: 20k threads is a bad idea in any language.  You can't just create more threads and get linear gains in performance, that's not how CPU's work.  Also, your threads don't produce anything.  They just download a string which is immediately discarded because it is local to the function.  You'll want to batch these requests in a reasonable size.

Comment: You might wish to consider capping the number of active threads. You can read a file and create new threads much faster than they will complete.

Comment: @EdS. For testing purposes I wasn't returning the string in anyway, simply just seeing how fast request could be made to download the html, without threading its unreasonably slow, by creating the threads  i was able to process a few thousand each second; however. As I said in my initial post I thought they'd destroy themselves after the function was complete. Do you have any code examples on how to tackle this?

Comment: @user3037561: The threads are destroyed after they exit, that's not your problem.  Your problem is starting such a large number of them simultaneously.  Don't expect them to run and complete in a synchronous manner.  You're thrashing.  Threads are expensive resources.

Comment: @EdS. as I'm aware, but unfortunately I'm not aware of how to actually go about writing stable code for this task in a way that meets c# standards or at least produces quality results.

Answer (score 1):

One very reliable way to do this is by using the producer-consumer pattern. You create a thread-safe queue of URLs (for example, `BlockingCollection<Uri>`). Your main thread is the producer, which adds items to the queue. You then have multiple consumer threads, each of which reads Urls from the queue and does the HTTP requests. See [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx).

Setting it up isn't terribly difficult:

```
BlockingCollection<Uri> UrlQueue = new BlockingCollection<Uri>();

// Main thread starts the consumer threads
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessUrls, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessUrls, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
// create more tasks if you think necessary.

// Now read your file
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(inputFileName))
{
    var theUri = ExtractUriFromLine(line);
    UrlQueue.Add(theUri);
}

// when done adding lines to the queue, mark the queue as complete
UrlQueue.CompleteAdding();

// now wait for the tasks to complete.
t1.Wait();
t2.Wait();
// You could also use Task.WaitAll if you have an array of tasks
```

The individual threads process the urls with this method:

```
void ProcessUrls()
{
    foreach (var uri in UrlQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // code here to do a web request on that url
    }
}
```

That's a simple and reliable way to do things, but it's not especially quick. You can do much better by using a second queue of `WebCient` objects that make asynchronous requests For example, say you want to have 15 asynchronous requests. You start the same way with a `BlockingCollection`, but you only have one persistent consumer thread.

```
const int MaxRequests = 15;
BlockingCollection<WebClient> Clients = new BlockingCollection<WebClient>();

// start a single consumer thread
var ProcessingThread = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessUrls, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

// Create the WebClient objects and add them to the queue
for (var i = 0; i < MaxRequests; ++i)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    // Add an event handler for the DownloadDataCompleted event
    client.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompletedHandler;
    // And add this client to the queue
    Clients.Add(client);
}

// add the code from above that reads the file and populates the queue
```

Your processing function is somewhat different:

```
void ProcessUrls()
{
    foreach (var uri in UrlQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // Wait for an available client
        var client = Clients.Take();
        // and make an asynchronous request
        client.DownloadDataAsync(uri, client);
    }
    // When the queue is empty, you need to wait for all of the
    // clients to complete their requests.
    // You know they're all done when you dequeue all of them.
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxRequests; ++i)
    {
        var client = Clients.Take();
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Your `DownloadDataCompleted` event handler does something with the data that was downloaded, and then adds the `WebClient` instance back to the queue of clients.

```
void DownloadDataCompleteHandler(Object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // The data downloaded is in e.Result
    // be sure to check the e.Error and e.Cancelled values to determine if an error occurred

    // do something with the data

    // And then add the client back to the queue
    WebClient client = (WebClient)e.UserState;
    Clients.Add(client);
}
```

This should keep you going with 15 concurrent requests, which is about all you can do without getting a bit more complicated. Your system can likely handle many more concurrent requests, but the way that `WebClient` starts asynchronous requests requires some synchronous work up front, and that overhead makes 15 about the maximum number you can handle.

You *might* be able to have multiple threads initiating the asynchronous requests. In that case, you could potentially have as many threads as you have processor cores. So on a quad core machine, you could have the main thread and three consumer threads. With three consumer threads this technique could give you 45 concurrent requests. I'm not *certain* that it scales that well, but it might be worth a try.

There are ways to have hundreds of concurrent requests, but they're quite a bit more complicated to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need thread management.

My advice is to use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of creating your own Threads.

By using the Task Parallel Library, you let the runtime deal with the thread management. By default, it will allocate your tasks on threads from the ThreadPool, and will allow a level of concurrency which is contingent on the number of CPU cores you have. It will also reuse existing Threads when they become available instead of wasting time creating new ones.

If you want to get more advanced, you can create your own task scheduler to manage the scheduling aspect yourself.

See also [What is difference between Task and Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625664/what-is-difference-between-task-and-thread)